# Nginx not can't recognize files using if statement

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to perform an operation based on the existence of a file in the file system using Nginx 1.24.0 and Amazon Linux 2.

However, this code is always returning 404.

```
location ~ ^/test {
    if (-e "/tmp/hello.txt") {
        return 200 "file exists";
    }
    return 404 "not found";
}
```

- SELinux is disabled.
- /tmp/hello.txt exists with nginx:nginx + 777
- /tmp has 777
- IF statements are evil, we know it, but for some historical reason we must use if.

What could the problem be?